# D3 callback function's `this` shadows object's `this`

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have a class that's wrapping D3. I'm converting it to TypeScript and I'm getting the following two errors and can't figure out how to fix them (well actually there are multiple errors but they're all similar to this pair),

```
src/d3-graph.ts:295:19 - error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. 
295         d3.select(this)
                      ~~~~

  src/d3-graph.ts:294:23
    294       .on('mouseout', function(d: any) {
                              ~~~~~~~~
    An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.
```

Code (a method inside a class with line numbers added for reference),

```
...
1 private _enableNodeHighlightOnHover() {
2   this._nodes
3     .on('mouseout', function(d: any) {
4       d3.select(this)
5         .style('stroke-width', '2px')
6     })
7 }
...
```

Notice on line 2, the `this` refers to the instance object of the class.

On line 4, the `this` refers to the object D3 has bound onto the callback found provided to the `on` (line 3). Also note the use of `function` over `(...) => {  ... }` -- to allow D3 to bind the `this` to the object it needs to.

I'm more than happy to lose the `this` usage in the callback function if I can access the D3 object I'm using in `d3.select(this)` in some other way. But I'm not sure what that way would be.

There are other uses of this pattern that will need to be accommodated as well,

```
private _enableDrag() {
  const that = this

  this._drag = d3.drag()
  this._drag
    .on('drag', function(d: any) {
      d.x += d3.event.dx
      d.y += d3.event.dy

      d3.select(this)
        .attr('cx', d.x)
        .attr('cy', d.y)

      that._links.each(function(l: any) {
        if (l.source === d.id)
          d3.select(this)
            .attr('x1', d.x)
            .attr('y1', d.y)
        else if (l.target === d.id)
          d3.select(this)
            .attr('x2', d.x)
            .attr('y2', d.y)
      })

      if (that._nodeTextLabels === null)
        logger.warn(
          'enableDrag called before this._nodeTextLabels has been initialized')
      else
        that._nodeTextLabels.each(function(n: any) {
          if (n.id == d.id)
            d3.select(this)
              .attr('x', d.x + D3Graph._LABEL_FONT_SIZE / 2)
              .attr('y', d.y + 15)
        })

      that._nodes.each(function(n: any) {
        if (n.id == d.id)
          d3.select(this).select('circle')
            .attr('cx', d.x)
            .attr('cy', d.y)
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `_links` and `_nodes` ? If your types are corect (both yours and the library definitions), `this` inside a simple function should be correctly type. You can add an explicit annotation for `this` (`function (this: any, other params)`) but I recommend you debug why the compiler does not figure out who `this` is

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir _links and _nodes are the values returned by `d3.select(document.body).select('.node')` and `.select('.link')` respectively. Where those refer to html elements with '.nodes' and '.link' class respectively.

Comment: And if I specify a 'Selection' type onto the this._nodes and _links declaration in the class, I run into additional errors such as `selectAll` does not exist on type Selection. I used Selection because that seems like what it returns, but I may be mistaken (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3/v3/index.d.ts#L27)

Comment: As an alternative to `this`, you could use the second and third arguments of the listener function: `function(d,i,g) { d3.select(g[i])...` which is the equivalent of `function() { d3.select(this)...`. (`g` being the elements in the selection - see docs [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on) under `selection.on`)

Comment: @AndrewReid That's what I was really looking for. I must have overlooked that bit of detail in the doc when I read it. Thanks. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @AndrewReid If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to `this` try using the second and third parameters of the listener function:

```
  function(d,i,group) { d3.select(group[i] ... })
```

This works because when using `selection.on("event",function(){})` or `selection.each(function() {})`, d3 binds the current element to `this` for the provided function. D3 also binds three parameters to the provided function:

- the current datum (`d`)
- the current index (`i`)
- the group of *elements* in the selection, not the selection of elements (named `group` here)

When using:

```
selection.on("event", function() { d3.select(this); })
```

You are in effect doing the same as:

```
selection.on("event", function(d,i,group) { d3.select(group[i]); })
```

As `group` holds the elements of the selection and `i` is the current index, `group[i]` is the current element, which is the same as `this`.

Using `group[i]` allows use of arrow functions and environments that might alter the context of `this` while still accessing the current element.

Answer (score 2):

This error is also happened on cheerio using `each`, `map` and so on.

`TypeScript(>=2.0)` can specify function's this type. The following code can avoid *TS2683* error.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters

```
.on('mouseout', function(this: any, d: any) {

})
```